# ruta de controlador aparece duplicada en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy tratando de aprender a implementar una sola linea de controlador en laravel para manejar todo el CRUD.

con resource.

asi que me creé un controlador con el comando :

```
PHP artisan make:controller ReasignarController --resource
```

para crearme un controlador con todos los metodos listos.

y en la ruta web, hice lo siguiente:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ReasignarController;
Route::resource('reasignar', ReasignarController::class);
```

cuando intento entrar a esa ruta.

http://localhost:8888/reasignar

me sale el App\Http\Controllers, repetido y me marca error, como se podria solucionar este error?
muchas gracias.

error:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\ReasignarController] does not exist.
http://localhost:8888/reasignar
```

Este es el inicio de mi controlador:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ReasignarController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return "ok";
    }
.
.
.
```

Comment: claro, no lo encuentra por que, si el archivo que no encuentra, dice que lo busca en: App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\ReasignarController
se repite esta parte de la ruta. "App\Http\Controllers"